# htaccess RewriteRule creates only root-url, not the expected one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

here are some possible URL's i need to rewrite:

```
https://www.example.org/products/rubbers/1234-super-special-rubber
https://www.example.org/forum/2345-hello-world
https://www.example.org/3456-very-special-article
```

I want to remove all numbers and the - sticking to the number from the URL:

```
https://www.example.org/products/rubbers/super-special-rubber
https://www.example.org/forum/hello-world
https://www.example.org/very-special-article
```

What i tried so far (4 digits and -):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*[/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-.*$
RewriteRule ^.*[/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-.*$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works not as expected, it only takes me to:

```
https://www.example.org/
```

I also tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (\d+)-([^/]*) $2 [R=301,L]
```

this should work, but it cuts '/products/rubbers' away :(

```
https://www.example.org/super-special-rubber
```

How do i tell the RewriteRule to cut out the numbers and the first - ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The `$1` reference you use in your rule references the first captured group from your matching pattern, but you did not define any such group. That is why it is empty and you rewrite to what you call the "root URL".

Take a look at this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/\d{4}-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Yes, we are on a shared webhost and currently we can only use the .htaccess file to configurate the webserver's behaviour somehow. Your answer confirms our believings to switch to a vServer soon. I will try your solution soon :)

Comment: Sure, that is an option. But take your time for such a decision. You will obviously gain flexibility, but you will _not_ necessarily speed things up by switching to a vServer. Reason is that typical vServers are not exactly powerful compared to the systems behind web space offerings...

Comment: Yeah, depends on the host and the vServer itself, there are some which are pre-configurated and there are some which are not. We will see :)